# Is there a Windows keyboard shortcut to quit Firefox?

Tags: windows, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

On most applications (whether Windows, Mac, Linux), it seems there is usually a {<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>,<kbd>Cmd</kbd>,<kbd>Super</kbd>}+<kbd>q</kbd> command that will quit the current application.

On Linux and Mac, you can type this keyboard shortcut and it will quit Firefox (after asking "are you sure", depending on your settings).

Is there an equivalent keyboard shortcut on Windows? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> doesn't work (Firefox 34.0 on Windows 8.1).

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> isn't sufficient, because that merely closes the current window. If I have multiple windows open, Firefox doesn't quit. And on top of that, when I do quit, Firefox will only reload the last window open instead of all the previously open windows.

I know you can type (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd>), but that is a two-step process, requiring the keys to be lifted between the first and second combination (and I like to be lazy). Plus, this is only guaranteed to work in English (not currently an issue for me, but possibly for others).

Is there a setting in `about:config` that will let me set or enable a keyboard shortcut to quit the entire application? Or any other way to set a quit keyboard shortcut?

Comment: _“On most applications (whether Windows, Mac, Linux), it seems there is usually a {Ctrl,Cmd,Super}+q command that will quit the current application.”_ IMHO not true for _most_ applications. It is originally a Mac shortcut. Multi-platform applications might support it on other platforms but it is not a standard on Windows – Microsoft apps like Word or Visual Studio do not support it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Firefox support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/) says (for Windows):

> Exit: Ctrl + Shift + Q

(from [Keyboard shortcuts - Perform common Firefox tasks quickly](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_windows-tabs))

(retrieved with Firefox 58, Windows 10)

Comment: Stephen please help accept this answer. Confirmed to work immediately in Firefox Quantum 61.0.1 (64-bit) as well without any additional set-up necessary.

Comment: To disable: about:config > set these to true: (1) browser.sessionstore.warnOnQuit and (2) browser.warnOnQuit. See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1279145. Workarounds: https://askubuntu.com/questions/10880/disable-ctrlq-in-firefox-without-keyconfig-extension

Answer (score 5):

- Create a file named `'ffquit.bat'` and add the line `'taskkill /im firefox.exe'` Save.
- Create shortcut to this file and right click the shortcut and select properties.
- On the *Shortcut* tab, assign a shortcut key (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for example)
- Under the Run menu, select minimized.
- Under *Advanced*, select 'Run as Administrator'. Click OK to save and close the Properties window.

Now every time you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> Firefox will quit.

Comment: This is an interesting technique.  What are the consequences, if any, of having the OS forcekill the Firefox process instead of terminating Firefox via its own standard user interface?

Comment: I'm assuming that as I am not invoking the /F(force) command that the process ends cleanly. I may be mistaken, although whenever firefox closes incorrectly it informs you and tries to recover tabs. I don't get that message when using TASKKILL

Answer (score 0):

Good question.  But unfortunately there is no standard shortcut for this, nor is there an about:config preference to create one.  You may wish to write a feature request and submit it on bugzilla so that the developers will consider to add it as a feature.

Answer (score 0):

The usual straightforward way is to run Task Manager with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, then choose the Firefox process in the Applications tab and pressing <kbd>Del</kbd> to kill it (or clicking the "End task" button).

(This is Windows 7; it looks somewhat different in different versions.)

Comment: I would use `ctrl-shift-esc` instead of `ctrl-alt-del` to open the Task Manager

Comment: That seems like even more work than `Alt + f, x`. But I suppose it would work.